# Selection without replacement - by mutating the list

Tags: python, algorithm, sampling

I am looking for the efficient function in Python that does sample selection without replacement, but by actually mutating the original list. That is, alternative to this:

```
random.sample(population, k)
```

that removes the elements from the original list as the sample is selected.
List can be millions items large, and there could be potentially tens of subsequent calls to the sample function.

Ideally, I would like to do something like:

```
sample_size_1 = 5   
sample_size_2 = 200   
sample_size_3 = 100   
population = range(10000000)  

sample_1 = select_sample(population, sample_size_1)  #population is shrunk  
sample_2 = select_sample(population, sample_size_2)  #population is shrunk again     
sample_3 = select_sample(population, sample_size_3)  #and population is shrunk again
```

where `population` is efficiently shrunk between each call to select_sample.

I have some code that I could show here, but I am looking for hopefully something already available, or more "pythonic" than my while loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way would be to [shuffle your population](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.shuffle) so the initial ordering is random (if it's not already random). Then take elements from the end and remove them.

You can get the elements by slicing `population[-sample_size:]` and remove them using `population[-sample_size:] = []`.

```
import random

population = list(range(100))

# Shuffle population so the ordering is random.
random.shuffle(population)

for sample_size in [1, 5, 10]:
    sample = population[-sample_size:]
    population[-sample_size:] = []
    print(sample)
    # [79]
    # [66, 89, 81, 0, 38]
    # [18, 39, 90, 36, 11, 32, 63, 65, 72, 67]
```

You could also use `population.pop()` if you just wanted to remove a single element at a time (i.e. if `sample_size` was 1).

A function to do this would then simply be (assuming that your population is **already shuffled**):

```
def select_sample(pop, size):
    x = pop[-size:]
    pop[-size:] = []
    return x
```

Comment: The shuffle and pop approach is a good one. The one improvement I have to suggest is that `del pop[-size:]` is probably better than `pop[-size:] = []`. I'm not sure if its any more efficient, but it's certainly rather more direct about what it's doing, which might help somebody else (or even you, in a few months) trying to understand the code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that popping the list is really slow in the middle; removing at the end is one option as in [Ffisegydd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29052747/918959) and certainly fast. As another option, you could use the heap datastructure from [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html).

In the beginning you'd organize your data into the `heapq` as a tuple `(random, value)`; then use `heappop` to pop the values with lowest random number first:

```
import heapq
import random

heap = [ (random.random(), v) for v in samples ]
heapq.heapify(heap)

def select_sample(size):
    return [ heapq.heappop(heap)[1] for _ in range(size) ]
```

---

In this case you should choose popping the end of the list over this as it is guaranteed faster; but where the `heapq` excels is choosing a fixed size sample over an unknown sized population.